# ImageViews being cut off and resized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a three section relative layout for a login page.

The first section at the top of the page is 1 `Imageview` and 2 `Textviews`.

The second section is 6 `RelativeLayouts` containing 1 `ImageView` to the left and 1 `TextView` to the right.

The third section is a `Button`

[image]

The first four icons are ok on any device. The 5th and 6th are both getting resized or not showing up.

I would like to see all 6 but if 1 can't fit dont add it. How can I do this in a proper way.

Thanks - P.S Code is below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/newd_login_overlay"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linLoginText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:src="@drawable/login_logo_white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/newd_login_text_one"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/newd_login_text_two"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linLoginFeature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnLoginCreate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linLoginText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginSecurity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/newd_security"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginSecurity"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginSecurity"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_security"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginAntivirus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/newd_antivirus"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginAntivirus"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginAntivirus"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_antivirus"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginTracker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/newd_phone_tracker"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginTracker"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginTracker"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_booster"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginBackup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/newd_backup"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginBackup"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginBackup"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_backup"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginPrivacy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/newd_privacy"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginPrivacy"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginPrivacy"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_privacy"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginBooster"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/newd_signal_booster"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginBooster"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginBooster"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_tracker"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLoginCreate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/newd_login_btn"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/newd_login_btn_text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/newd_login_overlay"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linLoginText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/login_logo_white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_text_one"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/newd_login_text_two"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLoginFeature"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnLoginCreate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linLoginText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginSecurity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/newd_security"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginSecurity"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginSecurity"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/newd_login_security"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginAntivirus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/newd_antivirus"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginAntivirus"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginAntivirus"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/newd_login_antivirus"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginTracker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/newd_phone_tracker"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginTracker"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginTracker"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/newd_login_booster"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginBackup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/newd_backup"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginBackup"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginBackup"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/newd_login_backup"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginPrivacy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/newd_privacy"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginPrivacy"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginPrivacy"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/newd_login_privacy"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLoginBooster"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:src="@drawable/newd_signal_booster"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgLoginBooster"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgLoginBooster"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/newd_login_tracker"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginCreate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/newd_login_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/newd_login_btn_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```